# Main Arguments For or Against Using JVM

Tags: java, scala, jvm, playframework, lift

I'm currently self learning scala for my basic programming needs, with the intention of picking up the Lift or Play Framework afterwards to help me develop some web apps.

I hear a lot about the JVM, with a lot of mixed feelings. Could someone please sum up the main for and against arguments one should consider when deciding to use the JVM?

Comment: Do you know what the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_virtual_machine is?

Comment: This question is not a good fit to our Q&A format. We expect answers to generally involve facts, references, or specific expertise; this question will likely solicit opinion, debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion.

Comment: I'm sorry but this question is too vague and could be answered any which way. Please be more specific.

Comment: @AndreiBodnarescu Using a JVM appears to be a stated requirement. ;)

Answer (score 2):

For: You have to use a JVM if you want to use Java or Scala.

Against: As @Mchl points out, You can use an Android DVM.

Use a DVM if you want to be hard core, but I suggest you start with a JVM.

> I hear a lot about the JVM, with a lot of mixed feelings.

I know what you mean about mixed feelings. I don't know what to make of this question. ;)

Comment: Well... not really... Scala can be run i .NET, and Android apps are written in Java, but are not run by JVM. ;)

Comment: In theory, yes. In practice, have you ever heard of someone doing this? I think using Scala on a DVM is more likely than .NET (as Scala uses the Java libraries)

Comment: Yeah, it was a purely theoretical comment ;)

Comment: @Mchl No theoretical after all. ;) http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=scala+on+android